# Happens-before для поля объекта, используемого несколькими потоками. Способ: volatile

Tags: java, многопоточность, volatile

Пусть имеем на исполнении следующий код:

```
package attempt;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Writer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Main.x = 1;
        // Main.secret=true;
    }
}

class Reader implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // boolean unused = Main.secret;
        System.out.println(Main.x);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static int x = 0;

    public static volatile boolean secret = false;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        exec.execute(new Writer());
        exec.execute(new Reader());
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Можно смело заявить, что для данной программы нет никакой гарантии увидеть на выходе единицу, ведь поток `Reader`'а не обязательно видит сделанные потоком `Writer`'а действия (см. кэши процессоров).

**Вопрос**: правда ли, что если раскомментировать все комментарии программы, образуется 100%-ая гарантия того, что на выходе программы будет единица?

---

Другими словами: Точно ли будет так?

```
Main.x = 1;
  <<                             // внутри одного потока
    Main.secret=true;
      <<                         // между записью и чтением volatile
        boolean unused = Main.secret;
          <<                     // внутри одного потока
            System.out.println(Main.x);
```

,где "<<" - happens-before.

Comment: если в `unused` будет `true`, то да

Comment: Спасибо! Оформите, пожалуйста, эту информацию как ответ и очень желательно привести цитаты с переводом из достоверных источников с ссылкой на них. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: вообще с `newSingleThreadExecutor()` у вас гарантирован один рабочий thread и последовательное выполнение, так что и `volatile` не нужен

Comment: Я это знаю. Но давайте допускать теоретически, что это будут разные потоки... Хотелось просто показать, что поток writer'a выполняется физически раньше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы планируете запустить потоки параллельно, но Writer чуть раньше, volatile не даст вам гарантии `Main.x == 1`.

Модификатор volatile только гарантирует, что вы увидите все изменения Writer до изменения volatile переменной в Reader после её чтения. Стоит рассматривать его не как средство синхронизации, а как способ, например, корректно прочитать shared-флажок о завершении какой-то операции в другом потоке.

В приведённом вами примере можно проверять флажок в цикле:

```
while (!Main.secret) {
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
System.out.println(Main.x);
```

Comment: Таким образом мы имеем 100%-ую гарантию, что на вывод программы выйдет единица?

Comment: И посмотрите, пожалуйста, смежный вопрос. Для меня очень важно получить на него ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823998/wait-notify-relock-Обеспечит-ли-happens-before-между-потоками

Comment: Если вы проверяете volatile-флаг в цикле - да. Читающий тред дождётся записи единицы и выведет её в out.