# Wait-notify relock. Обеспечит ли happens-before между потоками?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как известно, освобождение монитора и последующий захват этого же монитора другим потоком соотносятся как happens-before, т.е. `T1[unlock:monitor1]<<T2[lock:monitor1]`.

**Вопрос:**
Допустим, что поток `T2` сейчас ожидает в `wait()` по некоторому монитору, а поток `T1` вызвал синхронизированный по этому монитору метод, из которого вызвал `notifyAll()` и отпустил монитор. Будет ли считаться, что отпускание монитора потоком `T1` (т.е. просто выход из метода) happens-before поток `T2` вышел из `wait()` снова забрав блокировку.

Очень прошу, ответьте на мой вопрос. Он каверзный и мне не хватает сил найти источники, где достоверно точно сказано, что выход из `wait()` включает в себя полноценный захват блокировки, и что happens-before правило для междупоточных relock'ов здесь будет сохраняться.

---

*ВНИМАНИЕ*: оставшаяся часть вопроса требует вникания. Вы можете дать ответ не читая остальное. Вопрос самодостаточно сформулирован и без примеров кода.

Иллюстрация вопроса:

```
package attempt;

import java.util.concurrent.*;

class Writer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Main.x = 1;
        Main.methodWait();     // (1)
    }
}

class Reader implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        Main.methodNotify();   // (2)
        System.out.println(Main.x);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static int x = 0;
    public static boolean flag = false;

    public static synchronized void methodWait() {
        try {
            while (!flag)
                Main.class.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Impossible");
        }
    }
    public static synchronized void methodNotify() {
        flag = true;
        Main.class.notifyAll();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        exec.execute(new Writer());
        Thread.sleep(500);
        exec.execute(new Reader());
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Для этого кода вопрос звучит *так*:
Правда ли, что строки `(1)` и `(2)` полностью обеспечивают собой happens-before? Если правда, то почему?

(Считаем, что `sleep()` в `main()` обеспечил, что writer физически раньше выполнился до ожидания в `methodWait()` чем reader вообще запустился в потоке)

Comment: [jls-17.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.2.1): "Thread t performs n lock actions on m.", [jls-17.4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.4): "An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m "

Comment: Да, действительно, всё чётко сказано. Огромнейшее Вам спасибо! При том я это смотрел до Вашего ответа, но было лень вникать. Вы указали, что там ответ, и я не пожалел времени и всё понял. Оформите сообщение как ответ и добавьте перевод, пожалуйста - многим в будущем, я считаю, поможет! Заранее спасибо!